# What are the ports of Age of Mythology: Extended Edition?

Tags: technical-issues, age-of-mythology

I want to open my router ports to play Age of Mythology Extended but the ports appear to be different than older versions of the game, for some reason Steam is not working correctly on my computer and I only able to play on LAN, can anyone give me the ports to open?

Comment: Port Forwarding is only required for Internet play (i.e. the outside world). LAN should not require one to Port Forward.

Comment: Yup I want to create a server and play with my friends on the internet

Comment: Oh, oops. I read that as "I only want to be able to play on LAN" lol. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

**Age Of Mythology: Extended Edition:**

I am finding no evidence stating that the Ports for Extended Edition are different than the original. I did find [these](http://steamcommunity.com/app/266840/discussions/1/558756255860053271/) patch notes mentioning you should make sure you have steam port-forwarded as well though. Please let me know if this helps or not. I'm still actively searching for evidence of this, I posted the original ports and steam ports in the mean-time encase others find this looking for the original ports (like I did).

**Original Age Of Mythology Ports:**

- TCP 28800-28805
- UDP 2300-2400
- UDP 6073

**Steam Ports:**

- TCP 27014-27050 (Steam downloads)
- UDP 27000-27015 (Game client traffic)
- UDP 27015-27030 (Typically Matchmaking and HLTV)
- UDP 4380

**Dedicated/Listen Servers:**

- TCP 27015 (SRCDS Rcon port)

**Steamworks P2P Networking and Steam Voice Chat Ports:**

- UDP 3478 (Outbound)
- UDP 4379 (Outbound)
- UDP 4380 (Outbound)